# Assigning a variable a value depending on its value

Tags: php, variables

To do this I have used the code below, but say if I had more values I wanted to assign to the variable this method would become greatly unpractical. What other ways can I achieve the same effect but more efficiently. NOTE: I do know mysql has been depreciated.

```
if(isset($_GET['sort_by'])){
    if($_GET['sort_by'] == 1){
        $sort = 'topic_id'; 
    }
    if($_GET['sort_by'] == 2){
        $sort = 'topic_id DESC'; 
    }
    if($_GET['sort_by'] == 3){
        $sort = 'mysql_num_rows($query) DESC'; 
    }
    if($_GET['sort_by'] == 4){
        $sort = 'mysql_num_rows($query)'; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some lookup array:

```
$sort_look_up = array(
    1 => 'topic_id',
    2 => 'topic_id DESC',
    ....
    // add variants here
);
// then
if (isset($_GET['sort_by'])) {
    if (array_key_exists($_GET['sort_by'], $sort_look_up))
        $sort = $sort_look_up[$_GET['sort_by']];
    else
        $sort = '';    // set some default sort
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `switch case` like

```
switch($_GET['sort_by']) {
case 1:
    $sort = 'topic_id'; 
    break;   
case 2:
    $sort = 'topic_id DESC'; 
    break;
case 3:
    $sort = 'mysql_num_rows($query) DESC'; 
    break;
default:
    $sort = 'mysql_num_rows($query)'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use Switch case instead of doing like this.
Here are the links:
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_switch.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
$sorting=array(
   '', 'topic_id', 'topic_id DESC', 
   'mysql_num_rows($query) DESC',
   'mysql_num_rows($query)'
);

$sort=$sorting[(integer)$_GET['sort_by'];
```

(BTW: really you should sort your data on the DBMS, and avoid running multiple queries)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this...please check the syntax..

```
$queryArr=array("topic_id","topic_id DESC","mysql_num_rows($query) DESC","mysql_num_rows($query)");

$sort='';
if(isset($_GET['sort_by'])){
        $sort = (isset($queryArr[$_GET['sort_by']]))?$queryArr[$_GET['sort_by']]:'';
}
```